# In IPv6 router gets the Router solicitation message, but not respond with Router advertisement

Tags: linux-networking, ipv6, ip-forwarding, sysctl

We setup a IPv6 network with two ubuntu systems and we make one PC as HOST and other as ROUTER(based on the concept of SLAAC). 
The host sent the "Router solicitation" message, but the router not respond with any "Router advertisement".

The corresponding configuration we done for router is

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.enp1s0.autoconf=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.enp1s0.accept_ra=2
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.enp1s0.forwarding=1
```

Can you please suggest any solution?

Comment: How did you set up the router?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt, from this document we seen that when forwarding is enable and accept_ra is 2 for make a linux machine as a router. Is it possible?

Comment: You didn't configure a router advertisement daemon?

Comment: No. Can I do this without a daemon?  If any daemon is mandatory for doing this, can you please suggest any inbuilt daemon in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments we understand that we can't make it as a router without the help of a deamon. We use the radvd deamon to solve this.

Comment: I don't know how to close this question, If anybody know, please do it

Comment: The solid green tick mark means that it is marked as solved.